# What are the Single European Sky (SES) and Functional Airspace Blocks (FABs)?

Tags: airspace, eu

[Air Transport World](http://atwonline.com/open-skies/european-commission-gets-tough-fab-implementation) is reporting that the European Commission has initiated legal proceedings against Germany, Belgium, France, the Netherlands and Luxembourg; for not implementing FABs by the deadline. A quote says:

> FABs are a cornerstone of the SES initiative and are intended to reduce the capacity, cost and environmental constraints that continue to dog Europe's fragmented air traffic management (ATM) system by establishing common airspace blocks arranged around traffic flows rather than state boundaries.

What exactly are SES and FABs, in laymans terms?

Answer (score 1):

SES = Single European Sky Legal Framework. It started in 2004 when the EU Parliament and Council adopted Reg 549/2004 (framework regulation), 550/2004 , 551/2004 and 552/2004 (interoperability regulation). Also, a very important regulation was 219 which established EASA! (All these legislation is called SES I... amendments later came in place along a myriad of Implementing Regulations) which dealt mainly with What and How the Air Navigation Providers (ANSPs) must provide ANS services. This legislation aims at Uniting the National FIRs (Flight Information Regions) into BIGGER FIRs (Called FABs - Functional Airspace Blocks). Most of the operational advantages of FABs: Direct Routes, lower CO2 emissions and lower fuel burns for air companies are True and EU citizens will gain overall.

Since FABs will include the airspace of more sovereign nations, from a legal point of view, FABs need to be created with a Multilateral Agreement in the adjacent States.

Comment: To me this reads a lot more like a *rant about SES and EU politics* than an *answer to the question*. Perhaps you can edit down to simple factual statements answering the key questions ("What is SES? What are FABs? How are the two related?")

Comment: voretaq7 ...specially for you: SES is a part of EU legislation, FAB is a concept comprising multiple FIRs. According to SESI, States in the EU are required to create FABs. I think this is all you need to know if you're not a EU citizen.

Comment: the point of my comment was that you should [**edit your answer** to provide that information](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/3499/edit) (and de-rantify it).

Comment: Agreeing with @voretaq7, this is a rant, not an answer to the question which was "What exactly are SES and FABs, in laymans terms?"

Comment: @voretaq7: The information in the rant is still relevant as answer as it explains the reason for the report quoted in the question. It should be worded neutrally, but I think it should be here.

Comment: @JanHudec It's the tone that I have a problem with: We're an aviation site, not a politics site, and if we start getting "ranty" it can turn off a lot of potential users. (It also seems like an incomplete answer - it explains nothing to me, the non-EU pilot, about what these things mean if I decide to go fly in Europe - but that could be because the rant is obscuring the info.)

Comment: @voretaq7 how the FABs and SES regulations will affect non-eu pilots is a completely different quesiton. and I'm sorry to to hear from pilots that my  answer is a rant about politics, but it's TRUE, SES and FABs are political things to start with, they are about regulations. ICAO is also about regulatioins. and I know from my experience that pilots don't like regulations, but it's not my fault :)